# Sign in with social media accounts without creating a WP account

Tags: login, user-access, social-connect

I'd like users to sing in with their social media accounts (facebook, twitter, linkedin, google+) without creating a WP account. This is for them to be able to leave comments on a website.

Is this possible and what's the best approach for this?

Comment: Something like this should work, untested: http://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/

Comment: This question is far *too broad*, I'm flagging it as such. See [ask] for some additional information. As far as I know most - almost all - approaches are skipping the registration process, but create an user account.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the question more specific. I'd like users to use social media login so that they can comment (to prevent spam and provide comment ownership). I was wondering if there is a good reliable plugin for this or whether I would need to program something myself, and what's involved. I was hoping that either way someone would recommend a plugin or an advice/tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across a [WPMU Dev](http://premium.wpmudev.org/)'s plugin called [Comments Plus](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/comments-plus/). It doesn't create a WP user. It allows to connect with:

- WordPress.com account
- Twitter
- Facebook
- Google

You can choose to disable any of this social media for signing up, however, can't add extra social media account at this point.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Try the Jetpack Comments system, included in the Jetpack plugin.

http://jetpack.me/support/comments/

Comment: It looks good! Although, I do have to have other social media networks - linkedin, google+. Potentially more, would be great to find a more flexible plugin on that front.

Comment: JP's comments system currently supports Twitter, Facebook, Google+, and WordPress.com. That fits the majority cases, and adding more is probably overkill. Most people have at least one of those accounts.

Comment: apologies, I haven't read the text very carefully, most scanned the screenshots and noticed that it's only WP, twitter and FB icons. I will try the plugin out and see how it works. Thanks!